# Highcharts json daily graph

Tags: mysql, json, highcharts

I am total zero in Highcharts.

What I have: some data, which taken from MySQL db and converts into json-file witn json_encode. I can make different json arrays with this data. Data is: timestamp (date(Ymd)), first integer and second integer (all looks like "20131219   12952   1226").

What I want to do:
graph with two lines: first integer and second integer. X axe is timestamp, taken from db.

So I want to ask: how should I do it? I have totally no idea. :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your your JSON data is in array format.

Just like `[1387457763000,87]`

Answer (score 0):

How your json looks like?

In json_encode, you need to use JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK to return numbers, instead of strings.

If you need two sereis, you need to have 2-dimenstional array.